# Playing Audio file

Tags: android

I use the following code to play audio from sdcard. But it doesn't play, even doesn't throw error. My file is in the following path /sdcard/media/blueeye.mp3. Any suggestions.

```
public void audioPlayer(){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(mp.setDataSource(getExternalFilesDir() + "/media/blueeye.mp3"); );
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `/mnt/sdcard/media/blueeye.mp3` and please use `getExternalFilesDir()`:

```
mp.setDataSource(getExternalFilesDir() + "/media/blueeye.mp3");
```

Also, If you'd set your own onErrorListener, you will be able to see easily what the problem is.